# Spring boot + Hibernate + JPA No transactional EntityManager available

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am using spring boot 1.2.3.RELEASE version with JPA over hibernate. I am experiencing following exception

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No transactional EntityManager available; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:410) ~[EntityManagerFactoryUtils.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:223) ~[HibernateJpaDialect.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417) ~[AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[DataAccessUtils.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [ReflectiveMethodInvocation.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122) ~[CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.class:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [ReflectiveMethodInvocation.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [ExposeInvocationInterceptor.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [ReflectiveMethodInvocation.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [JdkDynamicAopProxy.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.deleteByCustomerId(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:275) ~[SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.remove(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$DeleteExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:270) ~[JpaQueryExecution$DeleteExecution.class:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:74) ~[JpaQueryExecution.class:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:97) ~[AbstractJpaQuery.class:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:88) ~[AbstractJpaQuery.class:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:395) ~[RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.class:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:373) ~[RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.class:na]
```

Following is my program structure 
Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class WSApplication {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WSApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(Orders)
public class Order {
    @id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "customerId")
    private Long customerId;

    // getter & setter methods
    // equals & hashCode methods
}

public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {

    List<Order> findByCustomerId(Long customerId);

    // 4- @Transactional works fine
    void deleteByCustomerId(Long cusotmerId);

}

public class OrderService {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository repo;

    // 3- @Transactional works fine
    public void deleteOrder(long customerId){
        //1- throws exception
        repo.deleteByCustomerId(customerId); 

        //2- following works fine
        //repo.delete(repo.findByCustomerId(customerId).get(0));
    }

}
```

In above service class code, can anyone please guide me why 2 works and 1 throws exception.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, I make a quote of the [Spring-Data JPA Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) to justify why the `delete` method works in your case (I mean the option **2**).

> CRUD methods on repository instances are transactional by default. For
>   reading operations the transaction configuration `readOnly` flag is set
>   to true, all others are configured with a plain `@Transactional` so that
>   default transaction configuration applies. For details see JavaDoc of
>   CrudRepository

The `delete` method is actually a method of the `CrudRepository`. Your repository extends `JpaRepository` which extends `CrudRespository`, so it belongs to CrudRepository interface and according the quote above is transactional.

If you read the section [Transactional Query Method](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactional-query-methods) you will see that is the same that the option **4** and you will know how to apply a custom transactional behavior for all methods of your repository.
Also, the *Example 61* of the documentation shows the same scenario that the option **3**.

Now keep in mind that you aren't working with JDBC logic, in which case the database take care about the transactions, but within a ORM-based framework. ORM frameworks require a transaction in order to trigger the synchronization between the object cache and the database.
So you must be aware and provide a transaction context for methods that do ORM logic like `deleteByCustomerId`.

By default `@Transactional` (I mean without any parameter) set propagation mode to `REQUIRED`and readOnly flag to false. When you invoke a method annotated within, a transaction is intialized if no-one exists. This is the reason of why the *workaround* of @LucasSaldanha (the same as example *Using a facade to define transactions for multiple repository calls*) and the option **4** works. Other wise, without a transaction, you fall in the thrown exception of the option **1**.

Comment: The documentation should mention this more verbosely than already done. Thanks for your help

Comment: I guess you are referring to _Example 81_ instead of _Example 61_.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I found out a way of making it works.

Just put a `@Transactional` annotation  (org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional) in your **deleteOrder** method at **OrderService**.

```
@Transactional
public void deleteOrder(long customerId){
    repo.deleteByCustomerId(customerId);
}
```

I really don't know why the second works. I guessing that since it is an direct method from the **CrudRepository** interface someway it knows how to execute it atomically.

The former one is a call to the **deleteByCustomerId**. This call will be processed to find out the customer with the specified id and then deletes it. For some reason it makes the use of an explicit transaction.

Again it is just a guess. I'll try to contact some spring developers and maybe open a issue to verify this behaviour.

Hope it helps!

Reference: http://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/

Comment: Thanks but I am more after why deleteByCustomerId is not working. As per my understanding, spring should have started transaction automatically as it is doing for delete method.

Comment: Why would it, only the super methods are transactional, if you want yours to be transactional you will have to mark it as such. Next to that the answer is actually right (IMHO) as your transactional boundary should be the service call and not the dao call(s).

Answer (score 3):

I still got the `No transactional EntityManager available` exception even after annotating my `search()` method with `@Transactional`.

I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.stefanproell.at/2017/03/12/using-hibernate-search-with-spring-boot/) which describes how to set up Hibernate search in Spring Boot.

The issue for me was that I had a different dependency on `hibernate-search-orm`. The dependency which worked for me without any problems was

```
compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:5.7.0.Final")
```

After adding this to the gradle build file, everything worked as expected.

Hope this helps someone else as well.

Comment: This one worked for me, I am was using 5.11.0.Final and by downgrading to 5.7.0.Final I got it working

Answer (score 0):

SimpleJpaRepository class, which is the default class that Spring uses to provide implementations for repository interfaces.
And if you check the class you can see the function that is being called is having @Transactional

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteAllById(Iterable<? extends ID> ids) {

        Assert.notNull(ids, "Ids must not be null!");

        for (ID id : ids) {
            deleteById(id);
        }
    }
```